# How to add a string which contains \n as new line to html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some JSON:
`"body": "Bla bla bla\n- Bla bla bla"`

I put it in a DIV

```
var card_body = document.createElement("DIV");
card_body.innerHTML = obj.body;`
```

The result:

```
<div>
"Bla bla bla - Bla bla bla"
</div>
```

I have tried to make it a PRE instead of a DIV but that means it can't be styled as I want it.

I have tried to replace all `/n` with `<br>`, but that does not work either.

Please help

Comment: You could add `white-space: pre` to your `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to replace `\n` with `<br>` tag, you can try:

```js
var obj = {
  "body": "Bla bla bla\n- Bla bla bla"
};

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = obj.body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

---

Or just using `<pre>` tag:

```js
var obj = {
  "body": "Bla bla bla\n- Bla bla bla"
};

var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = obj.body;

document.body.appendChild(pre);
```